# Refactor a large js codebase

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a legacy code base. There are 5 js files, and each js files has 10k loc. And there are no **testcases** too.

Since I’m not an Js expert, I don’t know where to start from refactoring the code-base. The code base is also tightly integrated with DOM api calls.

Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: In past have refactored some jQuery codebases using KnockoutJS for cleaning up the data binding.   After that, added requirejs modules for separation.   Once it's there, it was easy to add in a SPA framework like Durandal.

Comment: @batman it's like asking how to beat the joker

Comment: i'd spell out what you mean by refactor - do you want to move to something like AngularJS?

Comment: Something to mvc pattern, so that the code is manageable.

Comment: This might be a better fit for one of the stackoverflow sister sites. I think there's a Programmers and a Code Review site. Try one of those instead.